# Skip if Result is Not a Numeric - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, skip

Warmest greeting,
Currently I have the code:

```
result = Range("E" & n) - Range("D" & n)
```

There will be a row of text which give the result not a numeric, I tried to add these code:

```
result = Range("E" & n) - Range("D" & n)
Lvalue = IsNumeric(result)
If Lvalue = False then
    n = n + 1
else
    'other code here
End If
```

But it still give me "Type Mismatch" error...How can I execute code

```
n = n + 1
```

when the result is not a numeric? Any effort is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are subtracting two number which is not numeric you may get the error .

So try to find out the both the cell is numeric or not and do your stuffs.

```
If IsNumeric(Range("E" & n)) = True And IsNumeric(Range("D" & n)) = True Then
    result = Range("E" & n) - Range("D" & n)
    n = n + 1
Else
    'other code here
End If
```

Comment: `If IsNumeric(Range("E" & n)) And IsNumeric(Range("D" & n)) Then` will work too.

Answer (score 0):

An initial recommendation: declare all variable types. You can force this by adding `Option Explicit` at the top of your module.

```
Option Explicit

Dim result As Variant
Dim n As Long

n = 1 ' Or whatever value you need to start at

result = Range("E" & n) - Range("D" & n)
If IsNumeric(result) then
    n = n + 1
else
    'other code here
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort!